# Why do Galilean transformations change both states and operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

When a Galilean transformation on a quantum system is performed, the states and the operators change:
$$|\phi\rangle \rightarrow |\phi\rangle'$$
$$\hat A \rightarrow \hat A'$$
I don't understand the interpretation of the transformed objects. What confuses me is that both the state and the operator change. Maybe my interpretation of the whole thing is wrong, because  I thought about it a lot and I'm not getting anywhere. I now write what should be correct for me.

Adopting an active point of view:  the observer is fixed and the state change so:
$$|\phi\rangle \rightarrow |\phi\rangle'$$
$$\hat A \rightarrow \hat A$$
I know it sounds silly but can you explain me the exact interpretation that should I give to the fact that even the operators mutate?

Comment: Could you add some references about your initial statement?

Comment: Maybe it is meant that both state and measurement device are moved, so the results should be the same (this requires both to change)